# CentOS How to upgrade openssh to 6.9

Tags: ssh, centos6

I have to upgrade openssh. 
I follow this [page](http://sharadchhetri.com/2015/01/18/how-to-create-openssh-rpm-package-and-its-upgrade/) just instead the [rpm](http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/) `6.7` to `6.9`

But When I run `rpm -Uvh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/*.rpm`

I had problem :

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    openssh = 5.3p1-111.el6 is needed by (installed) openssh-askpass-5.3p1-1                      11.el6.x86_64
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: **Why** do you need to upgrade OpenSSH?

Comment: That page is yet another thing on the Internet with bad advice. Don't even attempt to do it; you will only damage your system (and possibly beyond repair). And it's not even necessary.

Comment: because security issue.the security tool(openvas) said a isuue about 'x11_open_ helper()' . it said I need to upgrade to 6.9

Comment: You fix it by ignoring openvas and actually paying attention to the correct advice you were given below.

Comment: Please, listen to Michael.  Your tool (like most automated auditing tools) is stupid.  You can read a bit more about Red Hat's patching policy in [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/583455/apache-upgrade-strategy/583458#583458), with links for further exploration, if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

This bug has [been fixed](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-1552.html) in `openssh-5.3p1-104` already and this alone is not a reason to perform a major update of such an integral part as OpenSSH.

That said: If you don't need `openssh-askpass` (and why would you on a server?), just remove it. If you need it, you have to update it as well.

Comment: what is this ````openssh-askpass````  about??

Comment: `yum info openssh-askpass`: A passphrase dialog for OpenSSH and X

Comment: If you need to ask this question: Please stop what you are doing and only use the CentOS-supplied packages. They will contain all relevant security fixes.

Comment: Thanks Where can I find it?

Comment: Really? That is what `yum update` is doing. Please learn the fundamentals....

Comment: I try yum update, 5.3 version is the newest.

Comment: Yes, it will update to `openssh-5.3p1-104` (or  `openssh-5.3p1-111` in the next few days). This is the newest version supplied by RedHat and CentOS for EL6, it contains the fix and is the version you want to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26371/discussion-between-user2492364-and-sven).